# VBS Script to Check Port Availability in Windows

Tags: vbscript, wmi, network-protocols

I am trying to check preconditions for a certain piece of software.  I have a set of scripts that goes through and checks for things such as disk space, memory availability, etc.

I need to create a script that can check if certain ports are open and accessible.  I am using the WMI to check other network configuration items, but cannot find any references to checking port availability.

Anyone have any ideas where I can find a WMI construct to let me view and manage ports or any other ideas for how to structure a new script to check port availability?

Comment: Add to question title suffix "on current machine" for clarity. I was looking for same thing but a test for port available on remote machine before starting a client process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found a script someone had made a while back.  It uses netStat.  Should work on just about any windows machine.  I think I was blinded by my desire to use the WMI.

```
Sub PortMonitor (strCommand2)

  Set StdOut = WScript.StdOut
  Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  set objScriptExec = objShell.Exec (strCommand2)

  strPingResults = LCase(objScriptExec.StdOut.ReadAll)

  if len (strPingResults) > 0 then
     WScript.Echo "Established!"
  End if
end Sub

Dim strcommand
strCommand = "cmd /C ""netStat -n |find ""127.0.0.1:1137"" | find ""ESTABLISHED"""""
Call PortMonitor (strCommand)
```

OP: http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Server/2003_Server/Q_27476065.html#

Answer (score 1):

Use `cmd.exe` and `netstat`:

```
D:\ :: type openports.bat
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('netstat -an -p tcp ^| findstr ABH') do (
        for /f "delims=: tokens=2" %%p in ("%%i") do (
                echo %%p
        )
)

D:\ :: openports.bat
80
135
445
...
```

Note that this works for the German version of `netstat`, which prints `ABHÖREN`; for the English one, it is probably something like `LISTENING`, so you'll have to replace the `findstr ABH` with the appropriate expression for English.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different :

```
Function PortIsOpen(port)
    PortIsOpen = False
    Set StdOut = WScript.StdOut
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set objScriptExec = objShell.Exec("cmd /C ""netstat -ano -p tcp | find "":" & port & " "" "" ")
    strPingResults = objScriptExec.StdOut.ReadAll
    If Len(strPingResults) > 0 Then PortIsOpen = True
End Function

Msgbox PortIsOpen("135")
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code. See "[How do I write a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)"