# Running a Powershell script from cmd

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use a simple Port-Scanner as a PowerShell one-liner that looks like this:

```
1..1024 | % {echo ((new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient).Connect("192.168.171.1",$_)) "Port $_ is open!"} 2>$null
```

It works perfectly in a PowerShell Window. But, if I try to start it from a Windows Command Window (CMD), I get the following error message:

[image]

Comment: In cmd, inner double quotes need to be escaped. Use `\"`

Answer (score 1):

Your quotes are conflicting. Try using:

```
powershell '1..1024 | % {echo ((new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient).Connect("192.168.171.1",$_)) "Port $_ is open!"} 2>$null'
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you on PowerShellv2, why not simplify this. Use the built-in cmdlets.

```
powershell -Command "1..1024 | ForEach {Test-NetConnection 192.168.171.1 -Port $PSitem}"
```

Absolutely, PowerShell is cleaner, the present/future, and where you want to be, but you could do this VBScript as well.

> [VBS Script to Check Port Availability in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602516/vbs-script-to-check-port-availability-in-windows)